# Snake Game popup improving and for mobile use javascript

Tags: javascript, html, alert, game-development, arrow-keys

I recently made this game and wanted to ask how to improve it. I made an alert box inside the javascript for when the game ends. It works but it's not beautiful. so I wanted to ask how can I change the Color and the message on the top of the alert box? right now a webpage message has been written.
And I wanted to add that it could be played from the phone something like the arrow buttons. I found something for java but nothing for javascript and wanted to know if its possible and how do I doit?
here is the code:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'/>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<h1> <p align="left"><font color="rebeccapurple"> Snake developed by agente00mcm </font></p> </h1>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class= 'game'>
  <div id = 'home'>
    <canvas id='mycanvas' width='800' height='800'>
    </canvas>
    </div>
    <p>Press start to start the game!</p>
    <button id='btn'>START</button>
  </div>

  <script>
  var mycanvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
  var ctx = mycanvas.getContext('2d');
  var snakeSize = 10;
  var w = 800;
  var h = 800;
  var score = 0;
  var snake;
  var snakeSize = 10;
  var food;
  var drawModule = (function () {

  var bodySnake = function(x, y) {
        ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
        ctx.fillRect(x*snakeSize, y*snakeSize, snakeSize, snakeSize);
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'darkgreen';
        ctx.strokeRect(x*snakeSize, y*snakeSize, snakeSize, snakeSize);
  }

  var pizza = function(x, y) {
        ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
        ctx.fillRect(x*snakeSize, y*snakeSize, snakeSize, snakeSize);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
        ctx.fillRect(x*snakeSize+1, y*snakeSize+1, snakeSize-2, snakeSize-2);
  }

  var scoreText = function() {
    var score_text = "Score: " + score;
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.fillText(score_text, 145, h-5);
  }

  var drawSnake = function() {
      var length = 4;
      snake = [];
      for (var i = length-1; i>=0; i--) {
          snake.push({x:i, y:0});
      }
  }

  var paint = function(){
      ctx.fillStyle = 'lightgray';
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
      ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, w, h);

      btn.setAttribute('disabled', true);

      var snakeX = snake[0].x;
      var snakeY = snake[0].y;

      if (direction == 'right') {
        snakeX++; }
      else if (direction == 'left') {
        snakeX--; }
      else if (direction == 'up') {
        snakeY--;
      } else if(direction == 'down') {
        snakeY++; }

      if (snakeX == -1 || snakeX == w/snakeSize || snakeY == -1 || snakeY == h/snakeSize || checkCollision(snakeX, snakeY, snake)) {
          //restart game

            alert("Game Over \nYour Score: "+score);
            document.location.reload();
          btn.removeAttribute('disabled', true);

          ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
          gameloop = clearInterval(gameloop);
          return;
        }

        if(snakeX == food.x && snakeY == food.y) {
          var tail = {x: snakeX, y: snakeY}; //Create a new head instead of moving the tail
          score ++;

          createFood(); //Create new food
        } else {
          var tail = snake.pop(); //pops out the last cell
          tail.x = snakeX;
          tail.y = snakeY;
        }
        //The snake can now eat the food.
        snake.unshift(tail); //puts back the tail as the first cell

        for(var i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
          bodySnake(snake[i].x, snake[i].y);
        }

        pizza(food.x, food.y);
        scoreText();
  }

  var createFood = function() {
      food = {
        x: Math.floor((Math.random() * 30) + 1),
        y: Math.floor((Math.random() * 30) + 1)
      }

      for (var i=0; i>snake.length; i++) {
        var snakeX = snake[i].x;
        var snakeY = snake[i].y;

        if (food.x===snakeX && food.y === snakeY || food.y === snakeY && food.x===snakeX) {
          food.x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 30) + 1);
          food.y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 30) + 1);
        }
      }
  }

  var checkCollision = function(x, y, array) {
      for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(array[i].x === x && array[i].y === y)
        return true;
      }
      return false;
  }

  var init = function(){
      direction = 'down';
      drawSnake();
      createFood();
      gameloop = setInterval(paint, 80);
  }


    return {
      init : init
    };


}());
(function (window, document, drawModule, undefined) {

var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){ drawModule.init();});

 document.onkeydown = function(event) {

        keyCode = window.event.keyCode;
        keyCode = event.keyCode;

        switch(keyCode) {

        case 37:
          if (direction != 'right') {
            direction = 'left';
          }
          console.log('left');
          break;

        case 39:
          if (direction != 'left') {
          direction = 'right';
          console.log('right');
          }
          break;

        case 38:
          if (direction != 'down') {
          direction = 'up';
          console.log('up');
          }
          break;

        case 40:
          if (direction != 'up') {
          direction = 'down';
          console.log('down');
          }
          break;
          }
      }


})(window, document, drawModule);
  </script>
 </body>

</html>
```

and besides the Problem I wanted to ask how do you guys find it and if it Needs any improvement beside the alert box style.
thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

The alert box is a system object and cannot be styled with css. You need to create an element in your page that replicates the behavior of the alert if you want to style it. You can find plenty of libraries that do this such as:

- [SweetAlert](https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert)
- [jQueryUi dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)
- [AlertifyJs](https://alertifyjs.com/)

Have fun developing games :)

Comment: thx you for your help I wanted to ask if you could show me how to do it because Im not a game developer I dont know much and I would be really happy if someone would help me thx again